# Accessing array elements in lua does not work well

Tags: lua

When I have a function that return multiple values I can either store them in seperat values or use the `{}` operator to get an array.

To access the values I can either define a variable to store the value or access the array via `array[index]`. When using a temp var to print the value I code:

```
function myTest()
  return "abc", "def", "geh";
end

a = {myTest()};
v = a[2];
print(v);
```

which works very well. But when printing the "indexed array converted return value" from the function with

```
function myTest2()
  return "abc", "def", "geh";
end

print({myFunction2()}[2]);
```

nothing gets printed.

Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form:

```
{myFunction2()}[2]
```

is not syntactically valid. I get an unexpected symbol error for that.

You can write it like:

```
({myFunction2()})[2]
```

and then it works as expected.

Comment: note that you can use `luac -p <file.lua>` to parse a Lua file for syntax errors without executing it (Useful when your workin on a system that silently drops syntax errors)

Answer (score 3):

Just don't. When you want to immediately access the `N`th return value of a function, use `(select(N, ...))`, which does not create a new table (and thus creates less work for the GC)

```lua
function myTest2()
  return "abc", "def", "geh";
end

print( (select(2, myFunction2())) );
```

Note that enclosing a list of values in `()` truncates it to the first value; this is necessary because `select(N, ...)` returns the `N`th and all following values. `(select(N, ...))` returns *only* the `N`th value.